# Load Controller and HTML from different host in angularJs App

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an app in `AngularJS 1.3.x`.

The home page has two hyperlinks which will take you to two different pages providing specific service. 
e.g. Let's say I have Two Links-

```
 1. Scan(PROTOCOL://Host:PORT/AppRoot/Scan)                            
 2. Print(PROTOCOL://Host:PORT/AppRoot/Print)
```

As of now, the application is hosted on the same server, hence `RouteProvider` works fine for me.

```
 $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'
        })
        .when('/scan', {
            templateUrl: 'app/scan/scan.html',
            controller: 'ScanCtrl as scanCtrl'
            }) 
        .when('/print', {
            templateUrl: 'app/print/pring.html',
            controller: 'PrintCtrl as printCtrl'
            }) 
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

But Now I want to remove the dependency between `Scan and Print`, by hosting `Scan` functionality on a separate `server(Server-A)` and `print` functionality on a separate `server(Server-B)`.

Could you please advise how can I progress on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like you wants to reduce the load or improve performance of your current application.

In Order to have 2 separate links which are pointing out to two different servers, you have to host your application in those 2 servers as well. and as you redirect to any of the new links then new application need to be initiated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Lalit. That's one of the possible approaches, but Is there another way to achieve loose coupling? What I mean is, bundling an application into same package demand to rollback all changes. What is the best approach to have two separate packages for two different components in an application and deploy them onto same server and collaborate?